# Gradient exploding when using RMSprop

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

I am a beginner in the field of deep learning. I am trying to develop a CNN which uses VGG 16 architecture for bottom layers and has some layers I developed for last top layers.

After updating the network just once by using RMSprop with lr=0.01, alpha=0.99, eps=1e-6, the activation values become larger and larger through the network. For example, for conv2, the values change from 0.xx to a number in the tens. This results in NaN for the last layer.

It seems that RMSprop changes **some** parameter values, for example, from x*1e-3 to x*1e-2 (or 1e-2 to 1e-1).

However, I wonder whether such small changes really make the problem in deep learning as explained in the second paragraph. Does people call this phenomenon gradient exploding?

(On a final note, when I use SGD Nesterov, my network stays stable during updating.)

Comment: When gradients explode, the first thing to try is to reduce the learning rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to put your learning rate at 0.001.

Just a question for you, why aren't you using Adam Optimizer which seem to be the best optimizer in a lot of cases ? (It is even partially inspired from RMSProp that you use)

If you are interested in SGD optimization I recommand you to read this article which helped me a lot : http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/

Comment: Whatever I take for learning rates, it give me the same results that looks like gradient exploding. But, I solved this problem by using Batch Normalization. It seems that Batch Normalization is one of necessary tools for complex or deep neural networks. Now I am trying to use Adam and it looks Adam gives better results in terms of loss. Thanks for your answer.